# Uncaught ReferenceError: receive is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, referenceerror

(THIS IS FIXED NOW)
(if you want to use this remember to put it inside a  under the  and before the . End the body tag under  as you have to put it in the start and end of the code. 
So I am trying to implement a function where you can post your status and others can see what others have wrote based on the google login which you get in the start. I am coding the Javascript inside the html doc and I have one CSS next to it. I used the firebase hosting, cloud and realtime database with NODE.JS. A bunch of my code is based on this gentlemnan's video:
https://youtu.be/QuiZE5ZE4EE (Paul Baumgarten)
This is the exact error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: receive is not defined
at receiveUpdate ((index):141)
at firebase-app.js:1677
at fc (firebase-app.js:1677)
at bf (firebase-app.js:1677)
at cf (firebase-app.js:1677)
at Object.G (firebase-app.js:1677)
at firebase-app.js:1677
at Ag.g.wd (firebase-app.js:1677)
at og.wd (firebase-app.js:1677)
at Yf.Xf (firebase-app.js:1677)
```

Html:

```js
var config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyC1ls01V0-7A1nCnZwfnuBsUwaboTUOE1E",
  authDomain: "ariadnes-string.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://ariadnes-string.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "ariadnes-string",
  storageBucket: "ariadnes-string.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "737704779364"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

function login() {
  function newLoginHappened(user) {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in
      app(user);
    } else {
      var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
    }
  }

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(newLoginHappened)
}

function app(user) {
  // user.displayName
  // user.email
  // user.photoURL
  // user.uid

  function updateMyStatus(e) {
    var myUpdate = {};
    myUpdate.email = user.email;
    myUpdate.displayName = user.displayName;
    myUpdate.status = document.getElementById("clientStatus").value;
    fb.child("user.uid").set(myUpdate);
  }

  function receiveUpdate(received) {
    var data = received.val();
    console.log(data);
    document.getElementById("messages").innerHtml = "";
    for (var key in data) {
      var person = data[key];
      var p = "<p>" + person.displayName + " (" + person.email + ") said:" + person.status + "</p>";
      document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += p;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("clientName").innerHTML = user.displayName;
  document.getElementById("clientPhoto").setAttribute("src", user.photoURL)
  var fb = firebase.database().ref("whatsmystatus");
  document.getElementById("clientStatus").addEventListener("input", updateMyStatus);
  fb.on("value", receiveUpdate);
}
window.onload = login;
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>GSS</title>
  <link href="GSS_Home_Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<header>
  <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="GSS_Home_Html.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
      <li><a href="GSS_Login_Html.html">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label">
            <span></span>
        </label>
</header>

<div class="loginbox">
  <img id="clientPhoto" src="" class="avatar">
  <h1>Hello <span id="clientName"></span></h1>
  <form>
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <div style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <p>What is your current status?</p>
        <div>
          <input type="text" id="clientStatus" maxlength="100" placeholder="Status...">
        </div>
        <p>Other people have left the following status messages:</p>
        <div id="messages"></div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<section id="hideonmobile2">
  <div class="loginboxright">
    <h1>Latest News</h1>
    <form>
      <div style="text-align: center">
        <div style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
          <p>Currently working on website - desktop program under construction</p>
          <p>Welcome to "Gamer's String". Our program is buildt to make an amazing community where you can post, view and complete tips and tricks. Get your post to the top by leveling up or purchasing our pro version. <strong>Good luck!</strong></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>


<section id="hideonmobile3">
  <footer>
    <div class="footer-social-icons">
      <ul class="social-icons">
        <li>
          <a href="
        https://www.facebook.com/ariadnes.string.9" class="social-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </footer>
</section>
<section id="showonmobile1">
  <footer>
    <div class="footer-social-icons">
      <ul class="social-icons">
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ariadnes.string.9" class="social-icon"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.8.0/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>  <script src="#">  </script>
```

I did have a CSS but i decided it did not matter for the sake of this
I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome. `function receiveUpdate(received) { var data = receive.val(); ... }` -> `receive` is not `received`.

Comment: I am new around here. What exactly are you suggesting to replace?

Comment: Not saying this to be mean or anything, but that should be obvious unless you lack basic understanding of functions/parameters/variables. I suggest you take a tutorial/course on these subjects. [This one](https://javascript.info/function-basics) for instance.

Comment: Thats okay, would you mind explaining. ;-) Regarding your advice I am. I am doing my best to learn.. I am still 14 and have been coding for just 2 year non professionally.

Comment: Okay, so, the function `receiveUpdate` has a parameter called `received`, as you can see. Then the first line of that function uses the variable `receive` which has not been defined anywhere. This is probably a typo and should be `received`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Hugs and Kisses from Norway. I wil look into the course you suggested.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck :)